# How to add CoreData Model File .momd into MonoTouch project

Tags: core-data, binding, xamarin.ios

The MonoTouch solution includes two projects.

- MonoTouch Binding Project: API Contract interfaces for linked native
  ObjC library
- Test Client Application

The native ObjC library requires to include Core Data Model file (.momd). I have added it to the project of Test App.

But app crashes with the following error:

```
    Unhandled Exception: MonoTouch.Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: Cannot create an NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with a nil model
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging:void_objc_msgSendSuper_IntPtr_bool (intptr,intptr,intptr,bool)
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController.PresentModalViewController (MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController modalViewController, Boolean animated) [0x00038] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIViewController.g.cs:261 
  at CombinedControllerApp.MainController.<ViewDidLoad>m__2 (System.Object , System.EventArgs ) [0x0003d] in /Users/mahmood1/Documents/Projects/TouchNote-Prototype/CombinedControllerApp/MainController.cs:96 
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIControlEventProxy.Activated () [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIControl.cs:30 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00042] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:29 
  at CombinedControllerApp.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in /Users/mahmood1/Documents/Projects/TouchNote-Prototype/CombinedControllerApp/Main.cs:17 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: MonoTouch.Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: Cannot create an NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with a nil model
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging:void_objc_msgSendSuper_IntPtr_bool (intptr,intptr,intptr,bool)
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController.PresentModalViewController (MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController modalViewController, Boolean animated) [0x00038] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIViewController.g.cs:261 
  at CombinedControllerApp.MainController.<ViewDidLoad>m__2 (System.Object , System.EventArgs ) [0x0003d] in /Users/mahmood1/Documents/Projects/TouchNote-Prototype/CombinedControllerApp/MainController.cs:96 
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIControlEventProxy.Activated () [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIControl.cs:30 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00042] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:29 
  at CombinedControllerApp.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in /Users/mahmood1/Documents/Projects/TouchNote-Prototype/CombinedControllerApp/Main.cs:17
```

How to add this needed CoreData Model File into Test Application that it will be visible for the native library?

Thanks!

(Sources are here : http://www.axifile.com/en/71EC96914A)

Comment: Have you tried just adding the file to the test project? Make sure it is set to `Build Action` of `Content`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my comment:

Adding most files like this to your project with `Build Action` of `Content` will solve the issue.